# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_all() on a non-object in web hosting

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch, mysql-error-1064

I need your help
Tried the following and getting fatal error.

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_all() on a non-object

```
function getMenusuno()
 {
global $conex;
$respuesta= mysqli_query ($conex, "SELECT M.menu_nombre, M.menu_ruta FROM   privilegios P INNER JOIN menus M ON P.menu_id = M.menu_id WHERE   tipousu_id='".$_SESSION['resultipo']."' AND M.menu_id BETWEEN '1' AND '4' ORDER BY p.menu_id ASC");
return $respuesta->fetch_all();
}

function conectar()
{
global $conex;
$conex = @mysqli_connect  ('localhost','user','xxxx,','doceispu_sisdocprueba');
@mysqli_set_charset($conex, 'utf8');
}
```

When I work locally no problem

In a web hosting, the error occurs. Please help!!!

Comment: Check your $conex probably you are using your local config.

Comment: $conex using web hosting configuration!!?

Comment: Yes, chech if you are using your MySQL web host configuration

Comment: `@mysqli_connect` will never raise an error, even when it should, because the `@` operator suppresses error messages. Remove the `@` symbol from `mysqli_connect` and `mysqli_set_charset`, then add the statement `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the beginning of your code.

Comment: Now the error Call to undefined method mysqli_result :: fetch_all ()???

Answer (score -1):

In such situation, add a debug statement after you mysqli_query instruction to find yourself.

```
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($respuesta); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: In such a situation it is clear that there is nothing useful in the $respuesta

Answer (score -1):

1. check your connection parameters & check whether mysqli is enable in your web server or not

Comment: Were it was a connection, the error message would have been different